# xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator clang unable to cross compile after xcode6-beta7

Tags: xcode

I use "xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator clang" for CC when configuring ffmpeg.

xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator clang is unable to create an executable file.
If xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator clang is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option.
Only do this if you know what cross compiling means.
C compiler test failed.

xcode5 is ok.

=========== Update ========
I added a test, it seems clang not link _start for simulator.

```
AGSPC98:pwd fluke$ cat> ~/tmp/ios.c
int main(void){ return 0; }
AGSPC98:pwd fluke$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -fasm -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -g -fno-inline-functions -O0 -falign-functions=4 -DDEBUG=1 -DVPLAYER_IOS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -c -o ~/tmp/ios.o ~/tmp/ios.c
AGSPC98:pwd fluke$ 
AGSPC98:pwd fluke$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -o ~/tmp/ios ~/tmp/ios.o
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
AGSPC98:pwd fluke$ nm ~/tmp/ios.o 
00000000 T _main
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `-miphoneos-version-min=5.0` to `-miphoneos-version-min=6.0` makes everything right.